# Worker role and web role counterpart in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, azure, web-applications

I am currently working with MS Azure. There I have a worker role and a web role. In worker role I start an infinite loop to process some data continously. The web role is performing the interaction with the client. There I use a MVC Framework, which on server side is written in C# and on client side in Javascript.

Now I'm interested in GAE engine. I read a lot about the app engine. I want to build an application in Python. But I don't really understand the architecture. Is there a counterpart in the project structure like the worker and web role in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to what you want is what Google App Engine calls modules. Modules are (roughly) pools of instances that can be set up with different runtimes and performance characteristics:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

I'm not an expert with Azure, but the big difference I see between GAE's approach and Azure's is that, unlike in Azure, "back-end modules" (not an official term) in GAE are still basically web services at heart. Everything in the module is still basically written as HTTP handlers. So, the main ways you control that module are via HTTP: using push queues to hit HTTP endpoints, using cron to trigger HTTP endpoints that read from pull queues/the datastore/Google Cloud Storage, and/or making HTTP requests from your "front-end module" directly to your "back-end module".

Note that Google App Engine historically provided the concept of "backends" and "backend instances" that you could use for much the same purpose as modules for longer-running background processes. However, the module system is more flexible, and it is now recommended.

Answer (score 1):

yes there is. look at backend and frontend instances. your question is too broad to go into more detail. in general the backend type of instance is used for long running tasks but you could also do everyrhing in the frontend instance.

Comment: I think they have removed the idea of backend & frontend instance and replaced it with modules. So everything is just a module where you can call  anything to be a background tasks.

Comment: yes that's the new terminology but there are still module types where some shutdown automatically or have a maximum response time of 30sec while other module types do not have such restrictions.